# Why is my delegate method being sent to its parent view after being sent to the delegate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I apologise ahead of time for the question title. I'm not quite sure how to succinctly describe my issue.

I'm having trouble with this delegate method I set up. I'm trying present a simple login screen modally. My issue is my login view gets a method called to it after I dismiss it.

Specifically, Xcode logs this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance [memory address]'
```

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol LoginViewControllerProtocol;

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userPasswordTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *loginButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<LoginViewControllerProtocol> *loginViewControllerDelegate;

@end


@protocol LoginViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>
- (void)loginViewController:(LoginViewController *)controller didLogin:(NSString *)userName;
@end
```

LoginViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)login
{
   if ([self.loginViewControllerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(loginViewController:didLogin:)]) {
        [self.loginViewControllerDelegate loginViewController:self didLogin:self.userNameTextField.text];              
    }
}
```

The delegate: (TestViewController.m)

```
- (void)loginViewController:(LoginViewController *)controller didLogin:(NSString *)userName
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; 
    didLogIn = YES;

}
```

I can't see why the delegate method is being sent back to the dismissed view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:
I apologise for leaving this out. This occurs in the view controller that calls LoginViewController. The delegate method also exists here.

TestViewController.m

```
if (!didLogIn) {
        //launch login view modally
        LoginViewController* loginController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"LoginViewController" bundle: nil]; 
        loginController.loginViewControllerDelegate = self;
        loginController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        loginController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        NSLog(@"LoginViewControllerDelegate: %@", self.description);
        NSLog(@"LoginViewController: %@", loginController.description);
        [self presentModalViewController:loginController animated: YES];
```

TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@class NuanceGuidHandler;

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <LoginViewControllerProtocol>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *partnerGuidLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *userGuidLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NuanceGuidHandler *nuanceGuidHandler;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL didLogIn;
@end
```

Comment: Where and how are you setting your delegate?

Comment: You do not show where the delegate value is getting set. Also, its a really bad idea to dismiss the viewController in the middle of an action method. Why don't you use a dispatch to the main queue and do it there (so the Login Controller will be in a quiescent state.)

Comment: The delegate method is not being sent back to the dismissed view. The `login:` method is. Typically the IBAction methods are declared in the header file like: `-(IBAction)login:(id)sender`. How did you connect your `loginButton` to the `login:` method? Does anything else call `login:`?

Comment: In the method the delegate is sent, I create a new instance of LoginViewController, hook it up to the nib, and set te delegate to self. I hook up the button using the ctrl-drag option in interface builder. Nothing else calls this method. I'll try reconnecting everything in the nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate thing is a red herring.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController login:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance [memory address]'

Means a object of class `LoginViewController` has been sent the message `login:`, which it doesn't know how to handle.

You've connected the action to a method called `login:`, and in your controller your action is defined as `login`. The colon is all-important, as any doctor will tell you. Either disconnect and reconnect the action in interface builder, or change the login method signature from

```
- (IBAction)login
```

To

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender
```

Comment: Well, there it is. I checked my nib, and both of those exist. I removed the one that shouldn't and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing one of two things:

1. You don't seem to be declaring your delegate anywhere when you mush your modal view controller.

   modalviewcontroller.delegate = self
2. I'm not sure if this is causing an issue or not but you have a double protocol declaration in LoginViewController.h.  This has messed with my delegate stuff in the past, and it may or may not be causing your problem.

Comment: the "double" protocol declaration is not a problem. Quite the opposite. It tells the compiler that the delegate is actually a valid type and will be defined later.

Comment: You might want to learn some more Obj-C before you start attempting to answer questions - 2 is called a `forward declaration` and is quite common in use - in fact for this code it is necessary because his protocol is created *after* the delegate is declared.

Comment: I apologise, I forgot to include the method where I set that up. I will update my question with that information.